# How to fix or work around apparent bug in plotly's event_data("plotly_hover") when interrogating 3d surface plots

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, plotly

I've produced an app where the aim is to combine four surfaces of values on a common 3D plane, with corresponding subplots that show cross-sections of z ~ y and z ~ x. To do this I'm trying to use `event_data("plotly_hover")` to extract the x and y values of the surface.

However, the maximum x value recorded by `event_data("plotly_hover")` is truncated at around 38, whereas the maximum x value is 80. The tooltips for the surface itself, however, are correct.

[image: Image showing both hover-over tooltips and event_data("plotly_hover") output working correctly]

[image: Image showing both hover-over tooltips and event_data("plotly_hover") output; the latter now not working correctly]

This is shown in the two figures: the first shows both the tooltip and `event_data()` output where x < 38, both of which are correct; and the latter shows the tooltip and event_data where x > 38. The tooltip correctly describes the corresponding values, but the event_data output is stuck at the last position where x == 38.

The code is reproduced below (much of which is about the construction of the tooltip). Any suggestions for why `event_data` is not working correctly in this instance, and suggested solutions (either using event_data or a work-around) are much appreciated.

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(plotly)
read_csv("https://github.com/JonMinton/housing_tenure_explorer/blob/master/data/FRS%20HBAI%20-%20tables%20v1.csv?raw=true") %>% 
#read_csv("data/FRS HBAI - tables v1.csv") %>% 
  select(
    region = regname, year = yearcode, age = age2, tenure = tenurename, n = N_ten4s, N = N_all2
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    proportion = n / N
  ) -> dta 

regions <- unique(dta$region)

tenure_types <- unique(dta$tenure)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Minimal example"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotlyOutput("3d_surface_overlaid"),
         verbatimTextOutput("selection")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$`3d_surface_overlaid` <- renderPlotly({
    # Start with a fixed example 

    matrixify <- function(X, colname){
      tmp <- X %>% 
        select(year, age, !!colname)
      tmp %>% spread(age, !!colname) -> tmp
      years <- pull(tmp, year)
      tmp <- tmp %>% select(-year)
      ages <- as.numeric(names(tmp))
      mtrx <- as.matrix(tmp)
      return(list(ages = ages, years = years, vals = mtrx))
    }


    dta_ss <- dta %>% 
      filter(region == "UK") %>% 
      select(year, age, tenure, proportion) 

    surface_oo <- dta_ss %>% 
      filter(tenure == "Owner occupier") %>% 
      matrixify("proportion")

    surface_sr <- dta_ss %>% 
      filter(tenure == "Social rent") %>% 
      matrixify("proportion")

    surface_pr <- dta_ss %>% 
      filter(tenure == "Private rent") %>% 
      matrixify("proportion")

    surface_rf <- dta_ss %>% 
      filter(tenure == "Care of/rent free") %>% 
      matrixify("proportion")


    tooltip_oo <- surface_oo

    tooltip_sr <- surface_sr

    tooltip_pr <- surface_pr

    tooltip_rf <- surface_rf

    custom_text <- paste0(
      "Year: ", rep(tooltip_oo$years, times = length(tooltip_oo$ages)), "\t",
      "Age: ", rep(tooltip_oo$ages, each = length(tooltip_oo$years)), "\n",
      "Composition: ", 
      "OO: ", round(tooltip_oo$vals, 2), "; ",
      "SR: ", round(tooltip_sr$vals, 2), "; ",
      "PR: ", round(tooltip_pr$vals, 2), "; ",
      "Other: ", round(tooltip_rf$vals, 2)
    ) %>% 
      matrix(length(tooltip_oo$years), length(tooltip_oo$ages))

    custom_oo <- paste0(
      "Owner occupation: ", 100 * round(tooltip_oo$vals, 3), " percent\n",
      custom_text
    ) %>% 
      matrix(length(tooltip_oo$years), length(tooltip_oo$ages))

    custom_sr <- paste0(
      "Social rented: ", 100 * round(tooltip_sr$vals, 3), " percent\n",
      custom_text
    ) %>% 
      matrix(length(tooltip_oo$years), length(tooltip_oo$ages))

    custom_pr <- paste0(
      "Private rented: ", 100 * round(tooltip_pr$vals, 3), " percent\n",
      custom_text
    ) %>% 
      matrix(length(tooltip_oo$years), length(tooltip_oo$ages))

    custom_rf <- paste0(
      "Other: ", 100 * round(tooltip_rf$vals, 3), " percent\n",
      custom_text
    ) %>% 
      matrix(length(tooltip_oo$years), length(tooltip_oo$ages))

    n_years <- length(surface_oo$years)
    n_ages <- length(surface_oo$ages)

    plot_ly(
      showscale = F
    ) %>% 
      add_surface(
        x = ~surface_oo$ages, y = ~surface_oo$years, z = surface_oo$vals,
        name = "Owner Occupiers",
        opacity = 0.7,
        colorscale = list(
          c(0,1),
          c('rgb(255,255,0)' , 'rgb(255,255,0)')
        ),
        hoverinfo = "text",
        text = custom_oo

      ) %>% 
      add_surface(
        x = ~surface_sr$ages, y = ~surface_sr$years, z = surface_sr$vals,
        name = "Social renters",
        opacity = 0.7,
        colorscale = list(
          c(0,1),
          c('rgb(255,0,0)' , 'rgb(255,0,0)')
        ),
        hoverinfo = "text",
        text = custom_sr

      ) %>% 
      add_surface(
        x = ~surface_pr$ages, y = ~surface_pr$years, z = surface_pr$vals,
        name = "Private renters",
        opacity = 0.7,
        colorscale = list(
          c(0,1),
          c('rgb(0,255,0)' , 'rgb(0,255,0)')
        ),
        hoverinfo = "text",
        text = custom_pr

      ) %>% 
      add_surface(
        x = ~surface_rf$ages, y = ~surface_rf$years, z = surface_rf$vals,
        name = "Other",
        opacity = 0.7,
        colorscale = list(
          c(0,1),
          c('rgb(0,0,255)' , 'rgb(0,0,255)')
        ),
        hoverinfo = "text",
        text = custom_rf


      ) %>% 
      layout(
        scene = list(
          aspectratio = list(
            x = n_ages / n_years, y = 1, z = 0.5
          ),
          xaxis = list(
            title = "Age in years"
          ),
          yaxis = list(
            title = "Year"
          ),
          zaxis = list(
            title = "Proportion"
          ),
          showlegend = FALSE
        )      )

  })

  output$selection <- renderPrint({
    s <- event_data("plotly_hover")
    if (length(s) == 0){
      "Move around!"
    } else {
      as.list(s)
    }

  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed there is something strange about the plot -- if you inspect browser console, it raises `TypeError: attr[pt.pointNumber[0]] is undefined` (this is when `if (length(s) == 0` in your code).

I guess you can report it as a bug to plotly. If you need something that works now, the easiest solution is to exploit the fact that tooltip is generated correctly and add javascript code sending its content to shiny server. There you can extract variables that you need.

In the example below data is updated (ie, sent to R) when you click on the plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(plotly)
read_csv("https://github.com/JonMinton/housing_tenure_explorer/blob/master/data/FRS%20HBAI%20-%20tables%20v1.csv?raw=true") %>% 
  #read_csv("data/FRS HBAI - tables v1.csv") %>% 
  select(
    region = regname, year = yearcode, age = age2, tenure = tenurename, n = N_ten4s, N = N_all2
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    proportion = n / N
  ) -> dta 

regions <- unique(dta$region)

tenure_types <- unique(dta$tenure)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Minimal example"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("3d_surface_overlaid"),
      verbatimTextOutput("selection")
    )
  ),

  tags$script('
    document.getElementById("3d_surface_overlaid").onclick = function() {
        var content = document.getElementsByClassName("nums")[0].getAttribute("data-unformatted");
        Shiny.onInputChange("tooltip_content", content);
    };
  ')

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$`3d_surface_overlaid` <- renderPlotly({
    # Start with a fixed example 

    matrixify <- function(X, colname){
      tmp <- X %>% 
        select(year, age, !!colname)
      tmp %>% spread(age, !!colname) -> tmp
      years <- pull(tmp, year)
      tmp <- tmp %>% select(-year)
      ages <- as.numeric(names(tmp))
      mtrx <- as.matrix(tmp)
      return(list(ages = ages, years = years, vals = mtrx))
    }


    dta_ss <- dta %>% 
      filter(region == "UK") %>% 
      select(year, age, tenure, proportion) 

    surface_oo <- dta_ss %>% 
      filter(tenure == "Owner occupier") %>% 
      matrixify("proportion")

    surface_sr <- dta_ss %>% 
      filter(tenure == "Social rent") %>% 
      matrixify("proportion")

    surface_pr <- dta_ss %>% 
      filter(tenure == "Private rent") %>% 
      matrixify("proportion")

    surface_rf <- dta_ss %>% 
      filter(tenure == "Care of/rent free") %>% 
      matrixify("proportion")


    tooltip_oo <- surface_oo

    tooltip_sr <- surface_sr

    tooltip_pr <- surface_pr

    tooltip_rf <- surface_rf

    custom_text <- paste0(
      "Year: ", rep(tooltip_oo$years, times = length(tooltip_oo$ages)), "\t",
      "Age: ", rep(tooltip_oo$ages, each = length(tooltip_oo$years)), "\n",
      "Composition: ", 
      "OO: ", round(tooltip_oo$vals, 2), "; ",
      "SR: ", round(tooltip_sr$vals, 2), "; ",
      "PR: ", round(tooltip_pr$vals, 2), "; ",
      "Other: ", round(tooltip_rf$vals, 2)
    ) %>% 
      matrix(length(tooltip_oo$years), length(tooltip_oo$ages))

    custom_oo <- paste0(
      "Owner occupation: ", 100 * round(tooltip_oo$vals, 3), " percent\n",
      custom_text
    ) %>% 
      matrix(length(tooltip_oo$years), length(tooltip_oo$ages))

    custom_sr <- paste0(
      "Social rented: ", 100 * round(tooltip_sr$vals, 3), " percent\n",
      custom_text
    ) %>% 
      matrix(length(tooltip_oo$years), length(tooltip_oo$ages))

    custom_pr <- paste0(
      "Private rented: ", 100 * round(tooltip_pr$vals, 3), " percent\n",
      custom_text
    ) %>% 
      matrix(length(tooltip_oo$years), length(tooltip_oo$ages))

    custom_rf <- paste0(
      "Other: ", 100 * round(tooltip_rf$vals, 3), " percent\n",
      custom_text
    ) %>% 
      matrix(length(tooltip_oo$years), length(tooltip_oo$ages))

    n_years <- length(surface_oo$years)
    n_ages <- length(surface_oo$ages)

    plot_ly(
      showscale = F
    ) %>% 
      add_surface(
        x = ~surface_oo$ages, y = ~surface_oo$years, z = surface_oo$vals,
        name = "Owner Occupiers",
        opacity = 0.7,
        colorscale = list(
          c(0,1),
          c('rgb(255,255,0)' , 'rgb(255,255,0)')
        ),
        hoverinfo = "text",
        text = custom_oo

      ) %>% 
      add_surface(
        x = ~surface_sr$ages, y = ~surface_sr$years, z = surface_sr$vals,
        name = "Social renters",
        opacity = 0.7,
        colorscale = list(
          c(0,1),
          c('rgb(255,0,0)' , 'rgb(255,0,0)')
        ),
        hoverinfo = "text",
        text = custom_sr

      ) %>% 
      add_surface(
        x = ~surface_pr$ages, y = ~surface_pr$years, z = surface_pr$vals,
        name = "Private renters",
        opacity = 0.7,
        colorscale = list(
          c(0,1),
          c('rgb(0,255,0)' , 'rgb(0,255,0)')
        ),
        hoverinfo = "text",
        text = custom_pr

      ) %>% 
      add_surface(
        x = ~surface_rf$ages, y = ~surface_rf$years, z = surface_rf$vals,
        name = "Other",
        opacity = 0.7,
        colorscale = list(
          c(0,1),
          c('rgb(0,0,255)' , 'rgb(0,0,255)')
        ),
        hoverinfo = "text",
        text = custom_rf


      ) %>% 
      layout(
        scene = list(
          aspectratio = list(
            x = n_ages / n_years, y = 1, z = 0.5
          ),
          xaxis = list(
            title = "Age in years"
          ),
          yaxis = list(
            title = "Year"
          ),
          zaxis = list(
            title = "Proportion"
          ),
          showlegend = FALSE
        )      )

  })


  output$selection <- renderPrint({
    input$tooltip_content
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. As you can tell my javascript knowledge is nonexistent (except for very rudimentary conditionalPanel expression use). 
I produced a more self-enclosed version of the same problem and asked as a separate question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483212/reasons-event-data-does-not-register-full-range-of-surface-when-first-dimensio
You can see from this example that the bug appears only when the first dimension of z is shorter than the second dimension.